# windows authentication not listed in IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-authentication, intranet, iis-8

I am using windows 8, and i am trying to create an intranet site using ASP.NET MVC. I found that windows authentication not listed in IIS authentication settings. So i tried enabling Windows authentication from the windows features in control panel (IIS under security) , But i cant see the windows authentication listed there. Can anyone help me how to enable windows authentication in my pc?!

[image: IIS authentication]

windows authentication not listed in windows features.

[image: Windows features]